Density of $X$ from observed density of $Z$ and $Y$ when $Z=X+Y$ (and $Y \perp X$)
I have $Z = X + Y$, with $Y \perp X$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X] = 0$ ($Y$ is basically an error term). I observe the distribution of $Z$ and I know the distribution of $Y$. I want a formula for the distribution/density of $X$ and/or the distribution of $X|Z$, as a function of the distributions of $Y$ and $Z$.
From the problem, I know that $f_{Z|X=x}(z) = f_{Y}(z-x)$, where $f$ is the density of the variable. So I thought it would be very easy to obtain my formula from there. But, when I apply Bayes, I find that
$f_{X|Z=z}(x) = f_{Z|X=x}(z) \times f_X(x)/f_Z(z) = f_{Y}(z-x) \times f_X(x)/f_Z(z)$.
This is not useful because I don't know $f_X(x)$ nor $f_{X|Z=z}(x)$. So I guess Bayes will only be able to give me a link between the two, but I need to find $f_X$ separately. I don't know how to proceed though (or if that's even possible). It seems to be a very simple problem, so I guess I'm missing something obvious... Maybe I should not put it in terms of densities but in terms of distributions?

Please explain how one can "observe" an entire distribution (of $Z$).  Don't you observe a sample of $Z$ only?

It's an abuse of language meaning that I observe the entire population of $Z$. Let's just say I know the distribution of $Z$ and $Y$ if you prefer.

It appears you are asking about the deconvolution.  It's a fraught operation, highly unstable, which is why it's important not to oversimplify your actual statistical situation.  But mathematically the answer is straightforward: since the cgf of $Z$ is the sum of the cgfs of $X$ and $Y,$ the cgf of $X$ is the corresponding difference; and the cgf determines the distribution.  However, it's impossible to observe an "entire population" of any variable with a density, because it has an uncountably infinite support.

Indeed deconvolution seems to be what I want!
So I should just write it in terms of cgf, show the cgf of X is uniquely determined by the cgf of Y and Z, meaning that the distribution of X is also uniquely determined by the distrib of Y and Z. Thanks for the answer!
